# What role does the FF2000 have in Monday Night Combat?

Tags: monday-night-combat

I just picked up this game on Steam and have not seen him yet, so I'm curious - what role does the Penny Arcade character known as the "Fruit F***er" have in Monday Night Combat?

Comment: should this have the penny-arcade tag? Surely it's not actually about the webcomic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell (seen it once), it has the same function as the MNC mascot running around, that is, you hit it and get money.

The FF2000 seems to give more juice and restorative items than money though (sample size: 1)

Comment: ran into him a few times today, pretty funny :P

Answer (score 1):

If you're wondering what he does, Yourdoom has the right idea in that he gives players money and juice for attacking him.

If you're wondering *why* the fruit f**ker from Penny Arcade is in MNC, you may be interested in [this article](http://kotaku.com/5746103/indie-games-character-exchanges-guaranteed-with-a-handshake).  It's nothing more than a bit of cross promotion.